# Why do the ending anchor points appear disconnected after I apply a brush to a single stroke in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke, brush, anchor-point

I would like to know a solution or workaround to avoid having the stroke appear disconnected after applying a brushstroke. Please see before and after applying a brush to stroke. I have already tried the alt/option method of connecting the path as well as "join" to make the connection; however, when applying the brushstroke, there is still a "pinch" along the path. Is the tapered brush stroke part of the problem? Or is there a better way to achieve a more seamless result when using an art brush? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid this, if you apply a brush which has non-fitting ends. Artistic brushes with fine tapered or hairy ends usually are hopeless cases.

Workarounds:

- add a normal stroke as the second stroke in the appearance panel
- initially draw an open path or split your closed path to open path with knife or scissors, move the ends and edit the handles for good looks
- draw something to cover the gap
- edit the brush shape (a complex job) to make the ends to fit, use the modified version only for closed paths

Here's an example. In the left an artistic brush is applied. In the right the path is the same, but the stroke is ordinary:

[image]